# SSRS Report Builder and Firefox

Tags: firefox, reporting-services

I have chosen SSRS to deliver ad-hoc reports via Report Models to my user. However I did not consider fully how this would work in different browsers.

I have now found that the Report Builder download (which is a Click Once application) does not work on Firefox. Instead of running and installing the application it only gives the option to "Save File". This puts the file ReportBuilder.application into the download list. When you then select to install it the install starts (the "Verifying application requirements" dialogue displays) but then there is an error. Details of the error are: -

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\hobsong\Downloads\ReportBuilder(5).application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading file:///C:/Users/hobsong/Downloads/ReportBuilder.exe.manifest did not succeed.
        + Could not find file 'C:\Users\hobsong\Downloads\ReportBuilder.exe.manifest'.
        + Could not find file 'C:\Users\hobsong\Downloads\ReportBuilder.exe.manifest'.
        + Could not find file 'C:\Users\hobsong\Downloads\ReportBuilder.exe.manifest'.

I'm surprised by this lack of compatibility. Is it the same for all Click Once apps in Firefox?

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the FFClickOnce extension to work on Firefox 4. I did so by opening the XPI extension file and modifying the 'install.rdf' to work for Firefox versions up to 4.0. I haven't played around with it too much, but it worked on SSRS 2008 R2.

http://www.mediafire.com/?ljqcod39sr1gd9b

Comment: A slightly easier method is to install Nightly Tester Tools https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/nightly-tester-tools/ which enables you to disable compatability checking in Firefox, and install older add-ons anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You could try querying Google for ["clickonce firefox"](http://www.google.com/search?q=clickonce+firefox) for some quick answers.

Or I could spoil you the fun and point you directly to [FFClickOnce](https://addons.mozilla.org/es-ES/firefox/addon/1608/), a Firefox add-on created explicitely to allow Firefox users to download and run Click-one applications.

Comment: This add on is not available for newer versions of Firefox. I have already tried various suggestions from the internet without success which I should have mentioned, sorry. This post was a bit of a last resort as suggestions on this forum are often successful and I didn't want to eliminate any replies by listing the things I had tried in case they were incomplete answers. Thanks for your reply.